# Keep getting 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
numbers = []

while True:
    n = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    if n < 0:
        break
    numbers.append(n)
    Mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)

    for xi in numbers:
        var = sum((xi - Mean) ** 2)
        if len(numbers) == 1:
            Variance = var
        else:
            Variance = var/(len(numbers) - 1)
    print(Mean, Variance)
```

It works to solve for the mean, but not the variance.  Thanks!

Comment: `sum((xi - Mean) ** 2)` is trying to call `sum` on one number.

Comment: Why did you use sum function within loop? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of var is incorrect, you must acummulate the values first, then divide them outside the loop. (The sum() function you used does not do that, it attempts to add the elements of a sequence together.)

```
numbers = []

while True:
    n = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    if n < 0:
        break
    numbers.append(n)
    Mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
var = 0
for xi in numbers:
    var += (xi - Mean) ** 2

if len(numbers) == 1:
    Variance = var
else:
    Variance = var/(len(numbers) - 1)

print(Mean, Variance)
```

Comment: Explanation? Fixing code without even pointing out the fix is a little weird.

Comment: Patience is a virtue @shadowranger - downvoting while the answer is being redacted is alittle bit weird.

Comment: You realize I have no way to know you're editing it? I vote on the answer as posted at the time I read it.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
var = sum((xi-Mean)**2)
```

is not the right way to get the variance, because the sum() function sums only one number in each loop, the best way to get the sum of every number is:

```
var += (xi - Mean) ** 2
```

so the code should be:

```
while True:
    n = float(input())
    if n < 0:
        break
    numbers.append(n)
    Mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
    var = 0
    for xi in numbers:
        var += (xi-Mean)**2
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        Variance = var
    else:
        Variance = var/(len(numbers)-1)
    print(Mean, Variance)
```